# Receive specific feeds from facebook using graph api

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios4, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am developing an IPhone app. The user can post to his wall and now I want to read ONLY the news feeds that was posted from the IPHone app. 
When I use

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=...
```

I get all wall posts, and I can recognize the one posted from the iphone app by the "application" node in the JSON response. How can I filter those feeds? Should I use FQL instead?
Thanks!!!

**Edit**: I tried using `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q={My application name}&type=post&access_token=` with no success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, FQL is the way forward, you can pass an `app_id`: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

So your query could be like: `SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND app_id = 'my_app_id'`

Comment: Thank you very much!! Is it posible to use it with the graph api (https://graph.facebook.com) instead of the old one (http://api.facebook.com)?

Comment: Well FQL isn't the Graph API but you can make JSON/XML requests via GET or use the SDKs to make calls that way. I prefer the former.

Comment: Thank you! it did answer my question and it is working just fine!!!.  The new graph api is more friendly (it gives more information in the answer). I would like to know if there is a way to use it for this...